# Spring bootRun failing with mysterious error after converting maven to gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I have a project that I just upgraded from maven to gradle w/ Spring boot.

My actual gradle build finishes successfully. But the bootRun command gives me this error (full stacktrace at bottom):

```
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/363b96dc672db32e6d54cd172bda7ed5

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
```

Gradle version:

```
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-04-10 13:37:25 UTC
Revision:     b762622a185d59ce0cfc9cbc6ab5dd22469e18a6

Groovy:       2.4.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.4 x86_64
```

This also happens on windows.

It appears the java command it runs to start is this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /work/builds/cm/build/classes/main:/work/builds/cm/build/resources/main:/work/builds/cm/libs/sqljdbc4.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.22/3bb94b26c2ad2f8755302aa9bf96f03b23a76639/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.22.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.4.3.RELEASE/79b4f3ebf23f86c2680cbd37a109272f4e782022/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.37/5b88395a68f17424476b7505a41179fba21cf904/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.37.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.castor/castor-xml/1.3.1/b452ccde8f0d132fb6bc0bb6b3390e43721105e0/castor-xml-1.3.1.jar:/Users/bryding/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ro.isdc.wro4j/wro4j-core/1.8.0/76c21f7a84a96d25e7edf43e5bf81707fcecff95/wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/9.0.0.M13/d43c496a2a4dc486f55f1fba4085245c619dd9a8/tomcat-dbcp-9.0.0.M13.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-oxm/4.3.4.RELEASE/d8ad912a13f1b23def6ad87e336a5fcd8692ab9c/spring-oxm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/au.com.bytecode/opencsv/2.4/66151f8e7f00426025da525c2d64ed78cbe3fd08/opencsv-2.4.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.5/6c6c702c89bfff3cd9e80b04d668c5e190d588c6/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/4.0.4.RELEASE/c52e77d38a48b33f955ab25156f15e564c9b616f/spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/4.0.4.RELEASE/67e6eccc73a9887a7ca262c7cac20f9b36ce5a5d/spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/4.0.4.RELEASE/cb303b01fe84ca8845312171c77c8b8ff9d4a272/spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/b1b6ea3b7e4aa4f492509a4952029cd8e48019ad/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0/da217367fd25e88df52ba79e47658d4cf928b0d1/commons-collections4-4.0.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.4.3.RELEASE/ffda06c2144d10239014407333c223a237b73ad7/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/3.2.1/88347e9a484152e9b80fbad7648d1b552a8cff78/flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-velocity/1.4.3.RELEASE/3e089882a6ba5a96f740e82b8a2ccc56487b5d09/spring-boot-starter-velocity-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.24/3f6b4bd4f8dbe8d4bea06d107a3826469b85c3e9/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/5af35056b4d257e4b64b9e8069c0746e8b08629f/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.2.RELEASE/c72938c86ed3beadb385f29bc2954c8ca3aa47ab/spring-boot-starter-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.5.2.RELEASE/a477a9bcf414bce26c702872354ae60b1ed832f0/spring-boot-actuator-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.castor/castor-core/1.3.1/b04616229151dd7ebb6d962962c9e68accb0c7e5/castor-core-1.3.1.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/9.0.0.M13/caf1954d2b27ec226dcf72ba78f40d93db134371/tomcat-juli-9.0.0.M13.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.3.7.RELEASE/2de9f59f3202965438f3a02057d6ad8274636044/spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.3.7.RELEASE/54fa2db94cc7222edc90ec71354e47cd1dc07f7b/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.3.7.RELEASE/34b66b0b7910122ef95ba4fff6da9238ef80a5de/spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.3.7.RELEASE/5257b6486e43d8c05674323fea5b415d4da72f38/spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.7.RELEASE/7b69fc68cdb74c1c92f72905af6995696fcb56aa/spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.3.7.RELEASE/3f243d685e4a8a78a0c291445c6d85560ec4d339/spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.2.RELEASE/9a21295c00a62bfaaa930ba5f7909fe26eea2562/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.2.RELEASE/bf431678f6e201fadac9b06f4627358c1554d4e0/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.12.Final/e58bf1c660e6706d8e2cbb53bae110f574366102/hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.12.Final/302a526f5058290e9cbd719a5caf9f248d344719/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/d81aff979d603edd90dcd8db2abc1f4ce6479e3e/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.1.RELEASE/fa362aecd78883991f57a5d64e19f34b57a2c34d/spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.7.RELEASE/fa0671826a42f6bac5145ffbc78075493dcb4e8b/spring-aspects-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.2.RELEASE/27f29876980c079b46be16b759eafe92720f3338/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.3/c845703de334ddc6b4b3cd26835458cb1cba1f3d/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/8ad72fe39fa8c91eaaf12aadb21e0c3661fe26d5/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/73a8001e7a54a255eef0f03521ec1805dc738ca0/commons-digester-2.1.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/2ceb567b8f3f21118ecdec129fe1271dbc09aa7a/velocity-1.7.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools/2.0/69936384de86857018b023a8c56ae0635c56b6a0/velocity-tools-2.0.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context-support/4.3.7.RELEASE/7e48f8daf207c06cf0229889a456073832359742/spring-context-support-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.5.2.RELEASE/46bb5d8c9ab5d3ef9e158ca5906ee7d3569befc1/spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.2.RELEASE/8a9b8c747bc2c86eefde10330cb2984541bcb9d1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/7a27ea250c5130b2922b86dea63cbb1cc10a660c/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.7/6c3257ef458ac58a8da69a6dca3d2a15286d88c8/jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/db28774f477f07220eac18d5ec9c4e01f48589d7/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.11/4d156969f12963b5f9232e9fe68ab710c3318ad5/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.7.RELEASE/305c8db0f9552948aec093528cd01393cc98a646/spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/3616bb87707910296e2c195dc016287080bba5af/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/5e731d961297e5a07290bfaf3db1fbc8bbbf405a/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/598244f595db5c5fb713731eddbb1c91a58d959b/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/2.0.0.Final/3e899258936f94649c777193e1be846387ed54b3/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/71e1cff3fcb20d3b3af4f3363c3ddb24d33c6879/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/1.13.1.RELEASE/4e4257f2eb3f191613b4b000d43e8d0c3ff4457e/spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/d9b193994609086ea1f067af07e0af5f53303d92/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.3.7.RELEASE/b761cc783e49b5aa998ac63a721495a9f0f69f9c/spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.24/e6a8629079856a2aa7862c6327ccf6dd1988d7fc/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.2.RELEASE/354320ef371fc4fc126d1bb8564cd73085a48823/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/2f6c8c0b646afe18e3ad205726729d3c4a85fe2e/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.7.RELEASE/d25b11a605589f176e3ecf1dcae62a991a18b377/spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/16313e02a793435009f1e458fa4af5d879f6fb11/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-chain/commons-chain/1.1/3038bd41dcdb2b63b8c6dcc8c15f0fdf3f389012/commons-chain-1.1.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.3.1/d1fd6b1510f25e827adffcf17de3c85fa00e9391/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/oro/oro/2.0.8/5592374f834645c4ae250f4c9fbb314c9369d698/oro-2.0.8.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/sslext/sslext/1.2-0/c86a7db4ac0bc450e675f3d44b3d64cdc934361b/sslext-1.2-0.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.8/66178d4a9279ebb1cd1eb79c10dc204b4199f061/struts-core-1.3.8.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.struts/struts-taglib/1.3.8/e87e9817bdf03c2367fb5f6d5ead953db2df4c21/struts-taglib-1.3.8.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.struts/struts-tiles/1.3.8/6d212f8ea5d908bc9906e669428b7694dff60785/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/45b426f7796b741035581a176744d91090e2e6fb/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.7/8b46f39c78476fb848c81a49fa807a9e9506dddd/jackson-core-2.8.7.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/60253815b897166903bf5ec41219c5bb15333a69/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/dfa65e7857d46630761c0571758a56f7cbd1e9ba/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/8613ae82954779d518631e05daa73a6a954817d5/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/864c8e370a691e343210cc7c532fc198cee460d8/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/bryding/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/4bfc12adfe4842bf07b657f0369c4cb522955686/commons-logging-1.2.jar com.COMPANYNAME.ClockmanagerApplication
```

My application's main function is booting up because I put a log message before the spring run method call and it printed it out. Here's the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("We are running code");
    SpringApplication.run(ClockmanagerApplication.class, args);
}
```

So I can see the "We are running code" message right after this command runs. But then eventually, somewhere deep inside Spring, System.exit(1) is being called (and no one bothered to put a message saying why).

EDIT:

Ok so turns out that the stack trace shown in the bootRun output is the result of spring not doing anything with runtime exceptions. At bottom my application is throwing a runtime exception due to a file not found exception, and Spring just doesn't show this exception. I changed my main method to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SpringApplication.run(ClockmanagerApplication.class, args);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("FATAL ERROR - Build NOT Successful: terminating Spring application");
        System.out.println(ExceptionUtil.getStackTraceAsString(e));
    }
}
```

And now I can see the real stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'translationManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to figure out context descriptions for messages.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.workforcesoftware.ClockmanagerApplication.main(ClockmanagerApplication.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to figure out context descriptions for messages.
        at com.workforcesoftware.clockmanagement.businesscomponent.TranslationManager.init(TranslationManager.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at com.workforcesoftware.clockmanagement.businesscomponent.TranslationManager.init(TranslationManager.java:55)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: Not posting as answer yet as not enough info. But the command line generated by bootRun might be too big. Create a pathing jar. Instructions here http://tuhrig.de/gradles-bootrun-and-windows-command-length-limit/

Comment: Well this happens on Windows and Mac. We aren't seeing that error either.

Comment: Neither was I. Gradle was just crashing like that.   Did you try? You can just paste it as us.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it, but it sadly did not seem to work.

Comment: See my edit with updated findings Strelok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this issue. First of all, see my edits. It's important to have a try catch about Spring's run method and print out the stack trace for any runtime exceptions that get thrown, otherwise you won't see the true cause.

The problem was just that a bunch of my files were in the wrong folder, and the exception messages were not that helpful to this end. I was using the wrong path for gradle's resources folder, and once I put the necessary files in src/main/resources, my bootRun was successful.

Comment: You're right. What would be nice is a link to some official documentation about this behaviour. i.e. why are the exceptions/errors being swallowed by Spring/Gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in TranslationManager line 25 according to the updated stacktrace. Most likely you're passing a null reference to your InputStreamReader. I imagine the stream is null.

Answer (score -1):

Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
Do you use :bootRun.
It has to be 'bootRun'

Comment: Yes I use 'gradle bootRun'